# Define flow type that excludes a particular type

Tags: flowtype

I'd like to have a generic function that takes a parameter of type `(() => T) | T`, like

```
const myGenericFunction = <T>(param: ((() => T) | T)): T => {
  if (typeof param === 'function') { return param(); }
  return param;
};
```

However, in this case, flow doesn't know that if I pass a param of `() => 1` then `T` is `number`, as opposed to `() => number`. How can I help flow understand that `T` should not be a function?

Comment: Could you clarify the error you're getting? Looking at [your test example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAFsBPAcQFNsKAnASwwDEBXbDfOnMAXjAB4AKgD4AFAAcAhjQlEAXGBGKAlDyFgBKgD7qlS+QNVgA3qjBg6UBfhJiKcS5OlEe3XgHIordp2xuVRsBoKfGYabDBHGRElAG4wAF9TQODQ8MiiGNR4zLNc3KS8s1QANykwfHlsZiIAI1oeYnIqWgYWNg4cZUMARligA), it seems functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow doesn't contain a "not" type (such as `$Not<Function>`), so I don't think there's a completely generic way to do this. However, if `T` can only be a subset of types, you can accomplish this with bound generics:

```
const myGenericFunction = <T: number | string | {}>(
  param: ((() => T) | T)
): T => {
  if (typeof param === 'function') { return param(); }
  return param;
};
```